# Sharing a URL via UIActivityViewController on Facebook Messenger Broken

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-messenger

I have been using UIActivityViewController succesfully for posting content to twitter, linkedin etc.

However when attempting to do so with Facebook Messenger I get a very peculiar behaviour.

Even though the link i am providing is of the form **https://something.com/whatever123** what the user that receives the share gets is a trimmed version of that ( i.e **https://something.com** )

I cannot put my finger on it for quite some time now. Any one of you ever experienced something similar to this?

*Code used that works with all other apps below*

```
    var activityItemsUsed = [Any]()

    activityItemsUsed.append(URL(string: urlToShare)!)

    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItemsUsed, applicationActivities: nil)
    //EXCLUDE ANYTHING YOU DONT WANT
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
    ]
```